# How to Perform Bulk Delete in Azure Resource Group using Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

The azure portal has  option to delete list  of selected resources in  a resource group with  single button click.[image: Azure portal screenshot for your reference].
How to perform the same operation using azure python SDK, instead of deleting the vm's one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The batch endpoint is Portal only and is not supported by SDKs. This issue for discussion: https://github.com/Azure/msrestazure-for-python/issues/74

(I work at MS in the Python team)

Comment: Okay,Could you refer me to the document where I can achieve the same through the REST API.

Comment: As discussed in the issue I linked, this endpoint is to not documented and not officially supported. You may want to open a support ticket on your Azure portal asking about this.